# please explain which one is correct and why?

Tags: grammar

Please explain which one is correct and why?

> I got a little confused because I didn't think about it carefully.
>
> I got a little confused because I had not thought about it carefully.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which one do you think is correct and why?  We can help correct a misunderstanding, but you have to help us out.

Comment: i think second one is correct because it follows the rule "the action happened before another action in the past will be in past perfect tense and rest in simple past  tense.

Comment: @ankit.please accept one of the answers and upvote it if your problem is solved

Answer (score 1):

Either can be right depending on when (in relation to the confusion) the not-thinking-carefully occurred. If you really read them with picky, picky attention, the two sentences have slightly different meanings.

The reason that the speaker got a little confused has a different time frame for each of them.

> 1) I got a little confused because I **didn't think** about it carefully.

I got a little confused about the issue because when I learned of it I didn't think carefully about it.

OR

> 2) I got a little confused because I **had not thought** about it
>   carefully.

I had an opportunity to think carefully about the topic in the past, but I hadn't thought it over as carefully as I might have, and when I learned of this new issue, I got confused.

The second explanation is a little more wordy, but if that were the situation being spoken of, the second sentence would be appropriate.